# onLocationChanged not being called (using PendingIntent)

Tags: android, location

I have seen other posts related to this, but I wasn't quite able to figure it out from that. I am implementing an android app that continuously updates and stores your current location. My debug log shows that it executes the requestLocationUpdates code, but it never executes the onLocationChanged code.

This is where I implement the location stuff:

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(102);
        mLocationClient.connect();
```

I have a button that records whether or not to store the location and this is located in the function for that button:

```
if ((mLocationClient != null) && (mLocationClientConnected) && (mLocationRequest != null)) {
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, pendingIntent);
                        Log.i("requesting", "updating");
                    }
```

And this is my onLocationChanged code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String display = "("+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()+")";
    this.lastLocation = display;
    updateUI();
    Log.i("location", "in on location changed");
    if ((mLocationClient != null) && (mLocationClientConnected) && (mLocationRequest != null)) {
        Point current = new Point(location.getTime(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        stroke_manager.addPoint(stroke_name, current);
        Log.i("adding", "points added");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are suppose to be passing a blank/empty intent? the intent does not point to anything so it wont do anything